# Azure Storage Deleted blob still available

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a link something like below to download my pdf from the Azure Storage

> https://mycompany.blob.core.windows.net/invoice/someuniqueid.pdf

which works as intended.

My problem is when I try to delete the blob from the storage, (which will make the file unavailable if I call the link again) it still downloads the pdf.

I understand this is because of cache or something.  But how or when does the cache clears?

Answer (score 1):

> I understand this is because of cache or something. But how or when
>   does the cache clears?

Your understanding is correct. Most likely the content was cached by the browser.

The duration for which a browser caches a blob can be controlled by `Cache-Control` property of the blob. By setting `Cache-Control` property appropriately (e.g. no-cache), you can instruct a browser to cache the content accordingly.